# How to host website from my home ADSL?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, adsl

I knew that I can use [DynDNS](https://www.dyndns.com/) to setup a hosting which will access my home adsl for hosting a website.

I entered there but couldn't figure out how to setup this in steps, I registered a host name but couldn't link to my router, I feel that there something's missed.

Also I checked [this article](http://www.sarin.mobi/2008/09/host-website-from-adsl-with-dynamic-dns/) but it didn't help me because I couldn't find options he is talking about in my router.

My router is D-Link wireless. And I have a dynamic IP address

Comment: Im also trying to do the same. I have a dlink router and I want to host my computer as a webserver. can you plz help me doing that???

Comment: For those looking for an answer: If you're on Linux or Mac, [Burrow.io](https://burrow.io) lets you host websites at home by just running a command. Check it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should install DynDNS client if your router does not support it. Second, you need to forward port 80 to the server machine.

You should not be able to link to your router from the Internet ("the outside") as this would be a security hole. Do you really need to configure it from outside? I doubt it. If you do, you should be able to set this in the router preferences.

---

Edited according to comments, thanks.

Comment: DynDNS support on the router is not needed. You can run a client on the machine to update tohe dynamic IP address.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, check DDclient http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ddclient

Comment: @minder I have created an acount in DynDNS. Im using port 8080 in both the port forwarding and iis8. when I try to open it through my ip address I get nothing. this is my account. decentkashifali.dyndns.info and this is my ip address 19.157.192.212

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your router you may not have the right options in it. But you will need to look for either port forwording, upnp settings, or Virtual Server settings. These will allow you to point port 80 at your "server." If all else fails you could set that port on your router up for DMZ, but this is NOT the correct way to do it. Thats only the correct way to open your computer and network up for trouble.

Oh and already stated, your ISP may not allow incomming port 80 requests. I know mine does AT&T, but they do not allow me to host POP3 or SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be easier and more reliable to just call your ISP and ask them to give you a static IP address.  The change should be reasonably quick (a few hours at most, mostly waiting for them to get to it).  It shouldn't involve any noticeable downtime, and should only cost an extra $1 per month or so.

Your ADSL would be slow for this, though.  Getting decent performance on websites is important, and difficult to achieve at the best of times, without the huge delays of going over ADSL.  If your "customer" connected through ADSL and your site is ALSO on ADSL, then they whole roundtrip for communication will go over ADSL ***FOUR*** times -- over their ADSL out, over yours in, over yours out, and over theirs in again!

Even the smaller professional hosting companies are moving to well-connected, high-performance virtual/cloud hosting provided by big players like amazon and google and rackspace instead.  Trying to get by on ADSL is at best an interesting experiment.  Not that you should rule it out if the monetary savings are an important factor for you, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Is this website going to serve more than a couple users? If so, it's going to quickly get slow. Most ADSL connections I've encountered have an upload cap of ~30-50 kb/sec. A site serving content at 30 kb/sec these days feels a bit slow, and that's if there aren't any other users hitting it at the same time. Get a couple simultaneous users and suddenly you could be serving content out at dial-up speeds - and that's if you're not using your connection for anything else!

Web space is cheap these days - $5/month will get you decent space on a site like Dreamhost, and $20/month will get you a virtual private server on a host like Slicehost. Are you sure you want to host it from home?

Comment: Depending on what the plans are for the site the basic $5/month is not gonna cut it for a LOT of people. I'm currently serving my site from home and have a nearly a 7gb MS SQL database humming right along. No hosting company is gonna touch that size without a dedicated server esp. not for $5 or $20 a month. I'm all for people hosting small sites from home. Some ISP's even cater to it and use it as part of there marketing. The poster wanted to know how to do it, not weather it would be worth while.

Comment: If you're running a site big enough to need a 7GB database and not making enough to pay for a dedicated server, you're a fairly special case.

Comment: As for what the poster wanted to know, there's nothing wrong with making sure they're fully aware of the downsides of what they plan to do.

Answer (score 1):

As an added trick, if you end up purchasing a **domain name** in the future, you can set `www.mydomain.tld` as a CNAME record pointing to your dynamic DNS `mydomain.dyndns.org` which will allow people to connect to your home machine with the vanity URL.

Also, as others have mentioned, there are **bandwidth problems** with ADSL connections. So, you may want to consider using a content distribution network, CDN, to help off-load some of your data. There are a couple of free/cheap ones you can consider.

However, ultimately you will want to set things up properly and this will be best accomplished with a proper service running in a proper server farm.