# For Hosting and publish a Website at Home Computer?

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to Host website from my home ADSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/127610/how-to-host-website-from-my-home-adsl)

Help please!
I am using XAMPP for my website. My website is almost ready now to publish. It is working fine in localhost. Now I would like to make it online (public). And, this is my main OBSTACLE.
I have already bought a domain. I want to host it on my computer which have windows server 2008r2 installed. However, I am getting a problem to publish it online. I have no further idea how to do. This is my first ever website. Hope some of you could help me. I would greatly appreciate your step-by-step suggestion.
Please send me step by step configuration method.
Thanks.

Comment: If this is your first website I would suggest you look at "shared hosting" instead of doing it at home.

Comment: Do you even know how to configure your domain to be directed to your home server.  Furthermore running a home server is unlikely to be allowed by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps are:

1. Install XAMPP on the windows server (hosting) computer. (or install Apache, mySQL etc separately)
2. Copy the website files over.
3. Connect the hosting computer to the internet.
4. Get static (fixed) IP for the hosting computer (from your internet provider).
5. Configure your router firewall to forward port 80 to the hosting computer fixed IP.
6. Configure your domain DNS to map the domain to the fixed IP you obtained in 4. Wait 48 hours for DNS propagation to access your website using the domain name.
7. Up the security on the server and XAMPP so it cannot be hacked into over the network.

Each  step requires more detailed reading. Google it or ask separate questions when you get stuck.

Otherwise just go for a shared hosting provider for less than a tenner and upload your files to their pre-configured server then point your domain name to their name servers. Wait 48 hours for DNS propagation to access your website using the domain name.